# how do you have 2 values linked to the same value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to get google sheets to return the same value in a lookup for 2 different searches. For example, in my attached sheet, I want the search for both Malaysia and Kuala Lumpur to show the sales for Malaysia. Is it possible without the use of exceptions? Writing exceptions into my vlookup is not feasible as it is not scalable. Thanks.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OuZjSr654wwKcMhEpArfYnFCdLjX_En4Cs18gSu4enw/edit?usp=sharing

Edit: link changed. to simplify my question, lookup to return the same value for 2 different lookup values. possible without exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

There are options how and my suggestion is to apply two lookup tables, (say named Larry and Feeder). The first (Larry) used in the way you expected to and the other (Feeder) to determine what value to lookup in you 'main' table. If each two adjacent columns wide Feeder would have a row for Kuala Lumpur | Malaysia as well as a row for Malaysia | Malaysia.

So in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2,Feeder,2,0),Larry,2,0)
```

or perhaps:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Feeder,2,0),Larry,2,0))
```